# Parsing txt file for word occurrences python

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to python and found a personal project for myself. I am trying to parse through a large text file to find word occurrences, but I cannot seem to get the code to work. It starts like this:

```
    file = 'randomfile.txt'
    with open(file) as f:
       word = input("Enter a word: ")
       line = f.readline()
       num_line = 1
       while line:
           if word in line:
               print("line {}: {}".format(num_line, line.strip()))
       print("Here are ___ I found with the word" + word)
       num_line += 1
    f.close()
```

This code will run but it will not give an output for search words, and I cant see a reason why not, unless python is not reading the text file in the path, or if the fourth line of code is not being read properly? How can I go about fixing this?

Comment: your `line = f.readline()` needs to be inside the loop. At the moment this only reads one line. You also don't need the `f.close()` if you're using the `with` context manager.

Comment: Once I put that inside the while loop, it complains that it is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
with open(randonfile.txt",'r') as f:
   word = input("Enter a word: ")
   line = f.readline()
   num_line = 1
   for words in line.split():
       if word in words:
           print("line {}: {}".format(num_line, line.strip()))

   print("Here are ___ I found with the word" + word)
   num_line += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that only read the first line, and never loop through the entire file.

```
with open(file) as f:
       word = input("Enter a word: ")
       line = f.readline()  # this is the only place you read a line
       num_line = 1
       while line:
           if word in line:
               print("line {}: {}".format(num_line, line.strip()))
       print("Here are ___ I found with the word" + word)
       num_line += 1
```

You should read the next line in the `while` loop, like this:

```
with open(file) as f:
       word = input("Enter a word: ")
       line = f.readline()
       num_line = 1
       while line:
           if word in line:
               print("line {}: {}".format(num_line, line.strip()))
           line = f.readline() # <-- read the next line
       print("Here are ___ I found with the word" + word)
       num_line += 1
```

Now you are reading through the file. The next problem is you only increment the line number `num_line += 1` once the while loop is over, you need to move this to within the loop so it tracks how many lines have been processed.

```
with open(file) as f:
       word = input("Enter a word: ")
       line = f.readline()
       num_line = 1
       while line:
           if word in line:
               print("line {}: {}".format(num_line, line.strip()))
           line = f.readline() # <-- read the next line
           num_line +=1 # <-- increase the counter in the loop
       print("Here are ___ I found with the word" + word)
```

You don't need `f.close()`, the `with_statement` automatically closes files. You can also loop directly over the file pointer `f`, to read each line, like this:

```
file = 'randomfile.txt'
with open(file) as f:
       word = input("Enter a word: ")
       num_line = 1
       for line in f: # step through each line of the file
           if word in line:
               print("line {}: {}".format(num_line, line.strip()))
           num_line +=1 # <-- increase the counter in the loop
       print("Here are ___ I found with the word" + word)
 # f.close() -- not needed
```

I will leave it for you to fix the print statement.

Comment: Thank you for this. I will fix the print statement, although I havent figured out what is wrong with it, since it works for the code. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
word = input("Enter a word: ")
with open(file) as f:
    for idx, line in enumerate(f):
        # we need to use lower() and split() because we don't want to count if word = 'aaa' and line 'AAAaaa' returns True
        if word.lower() in line.lower().split():
            print("line {}: {}".format(idx, line.strip()))
```